# Invertible matrices with integer entries has to be permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices with integer entries. Show that if $B=A^{-1}$ then $A$ and $B$ are permutation matrices (matrix obtained by permuting rows of the identity matrix).

If the entries are non negative integers then it is quite easy to show, but if the entries also involve negative integers then I couldn't show it.

Comment: And what about [2 0;0 2]?

Comment: Isn't $A = B = -I$ a counterexample to this?

Comment: @gimusi Its inverse is no integer matrix.

Comment: I would try to use the integer properties of trace and determinant maybe... just an intuition without much thought.

Comment: It is not true. The group $GL(n,\mathbf{Z})$ contains all matrices with determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: I think you actually mean permutations and sign shifts. Negative entries would not result from permutations alone.

Here is a start:
We know that $\det A \cdot \det B = 1$ and as both are polynomial expressions of integers we can conclude $\det A = \det B = \pm 1$.
Then I think we can work with cofactor expansion of the determinant... But I have not elaborated this yet.

Comment: It's false because [7 2; 3 1] is invertible.

Comment: The present Question differs from the proposed duplicate (which has only a "hint" Answer) in explicitly considering the possibility of negative entries.  The Answer given here is much more responsive, so I don't think closing as duplicate is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrices may have negative integer entries, then the statement is not true. For example,
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
both have determinant $1$, and so are invertible over the integers, and in fact $AB = I$. But they are not permutation matrices.

Comment: This example is nice because it shows it is insufficient for one of the matrices to have non-negative entries (also illustrated by @CrossRatio's Comment on the OP).